# Multisim: How to generate a sweep frequency?

Tags: multisim

is there a way to generate a sweep of square wave frequency in multisim?
I'm trying to test a device but I'd need the speed to increase from 100hz to 1 khz

Answer (score 0):

Found it. 
Voltage Controlled Square Wave (Master DB -> Sources -> CONTROLLED_VOLTAGE_SOURCES -> VOLTAGE_CONTROLLED_SQUARE_WAVE).